# How do I disable touch mode in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mode

I am using a desktop PC, where the touch gestures (touch keyboard button and checkboxes on icons) appeared after using TeamViewer yesterday, this is what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this helps

Open Computer, 
Click on View, 
From the right hand side, uncheck "Item Check Boxes"